# Como consigo colocar submenu dentro de um menu a partir de uma base de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho as tabelas na base de dados bem feitas, mas depois quando faço o código, o conteudo nem chega a aparecer, Queria ter ajuda sff´

o código que tenho é este:

```
$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT titulo FROM menu WHERE id_menu = 1 ORDER BY id_menu   ") or die(mysql_error());
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
   echo "<li> ".$linha[''] . " " . $home ." </li>";
} 

$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT titulo FROM menu WHERE id_menu = 2 ORDER BY id_menu   ") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT titulo FROM submenu WHERE id_submenu = 2 ORDER BY id_submenu   ") or die(mysql_error());
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
   echo " <li class= 'dropdown ' > 
  <a  echo $orgaosMenu;  href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' style='padding-top: 15px;border-top: 0px solid #3B7D26;'>" . $linha['titulo'] . "<b class='caret'></b></a>
     " . $orgaosMenu . "</li>";

     while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      echo "<ul class='dropdown-menu'> 
      <li>   " .$line['titulo'] . "   </li>";
     }
} 

$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT titulo FROM menu WHERE id_menu = 3 ORDER BY id_menu   ") or die(mysql_error());
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
   echo " <li class= 'dropdown ' > 
  <a  echo $autarcasMenu;  href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' style='padding-top: 15px;border-top: 0px solid #3B7D26;'>" . $linha['titulo'] . "<b class='caret'></b></a>
     " . $autarcasMenu . "</li>";
} 

$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT titulo FROM menu WHERE id_menu = 4 ORDER BY id_menu   ") or die(mysql_error());
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
   echo " <li class= 'dropdown ' > 
   <a  echo $militanciaMenu;  href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' style='padding-top: 15px;border-top: 0px solid #3B7D26;'>" . $linha['titulo'] . "<b class='caret'></b></a>
     " . $militanciaMenu . "</li>";
}     

$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT titulo FROM menu WHERE id_menu = 5 ORDER BY id_menu   ") or die(mysql_error());
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
   echo " <li  > 
  <a  echo $multimediaMenu;  href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' style='padding-top: 15px;border-top: 0px solid #3B7D26;'>" . $linha['titulo'] . "<b ></b></a>
     " . $multimediaMenu . "</li>";
}    

$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT titulo FROM menu WHERE id_menu = 6 ORDER BY id_menu   ") or die(mysql_error());
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
   echo " <li  > 
  <a  echo $contactosMenu;  href='http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_where.asp' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' style='padding-top: 15px;border-top: 0px solid #3B7D26;'>" . $linha['titulo'] . "<b ></b></a>
     " . $contactosMenu . "</li>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Preciso mesmo de ajuda, por favor....

Comment: adicione essas duas linhas no inicio do arquivo:
`ini_set('display_errors', true);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` e coloque as mensagens de erro.

Comment: esse linha aqui já emite um notice: `echo "<li> ".$linha[''] . " " . $home ." </li>";` um indice deveria ser acessado, acredito que seria `$linha['titulo']`.

Comment: seria legal passar o desenho do banco de dados..

Answer (score 0):

Parece-me que o problema está no mysql_fetch_array()... Não associa o nome das colunas ao array e por isso não podes aceder a $linha['titulo']...
Tenta antes usar o mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado) ou então o mysql_fetch_array($resultado,MYSQL_ASSOC);

Comment: nao percebi muito bem o que disse, 
o meu problema encontra-se no while que esta dentro do outro while, ele simplesmente nao coloca os resultados que peço

Comment: Tenta fechar a tag ul
Onde tens:
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                                                  echo "<ul class='dropdown-menu'> 
                                                  <li>   " .$line['titulo'] . "   </li>";

                                                 }
adiciona no fim 
echo "</ul>";

Comment: uma pergunta...
a tag ul devia estar fora do while?

Comment: Sim! senão no código final por cada </li> (list item) que fechavas ias fechar a <ul> (lista não ordenada)

Comment: A solução funcionou?

Comment: Não, a função nao resoltou, e nao descubro o erro